# Using CloudFront with externally hosted DNS, pointing to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, aws-certificate-manager, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to set up cloudfront with my ec2 instance. The domain is at dreamhost, and I've added a CNAME record pointing to the cloudfront url.

I'm using Lets Encrypt on my EC2 instance. If I use my elastic IP and set that to an A record on dreamhost, it forwards fine and everything works. If I point the CNAME record to the cloudfront url I get a 502 error.

Following the troubleshooting guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html), I checked my SSL cert using an online service and it shows that everything is fine.

What am I missing? Does the cloudfront url have to be added to my cert or what?

Also, I'm pointing the distribution's SSL cert to a cert hosted in AWS Certificate Manager, that I think is ultimately pointing at my origin. I pointed the cert to my url and added the CNAME record to verify ownership and all of that seemed to work fine.

**UPDATE:**

I plugged my ec2 public url into an online ssl checker and I get the below result. Perhaps this could be part of the problem? I get the same result if I enter my elastic IP. It seems like this could be the culprit, but I have no idea what the next step is. Back to googling..

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

From what I'm reading, I need to make sure the intermediate certificate is installed on my ec2 instance. I also learned that in Apache 2.4 the fullchain.pem file takes the place of the old cert.pem file as the `SSLCertificateFile`.

I modified the contents of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf like so:

```
   <VirtualHost *:443>
      DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
      ServerName "test.example.com"
      ServerAlias "test.example.com"
      Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/privkey.pem
   </VirtualHost>
```

After changing that and restarting the httpd service, i'm still getting the error on my url. When I plug in test.example.com into the SSL checker, it shows this:

[image]

Keep in mind the first screen shot I posted was using my elastic IP, not my test.example.com url, so the aren't really comparable. I unfortunately don't have a screenshot of what test.example.com looked like before I made the changes, but I'm still getting a 502 error, so it's not apparently fixing it.

**UPDATE 3:**

It looks like my response headers are showing `server: CloudFront` when I navigate to test.example.com, so that's a step in the right direction. I wasn't getting that at all before.

**UPDATE 4:**

I downloaded openssl and was able to get the following information. It's weird that the certificate chain doesn't even show lets encrypt as a source of a certificate.

I originally set up my EC2 instance using a letsencrypt cert using test.example.com. Then when I created the cloudfront dstribution I used certificate manager to create a cert pointing to my test.example.com I'm now wondering if I somehow configured that wrong since the openssl output shows only an amazon cert. I'm confused by the interaction between the certificate manager and the lets encrypt cert that both seem to be pointing to the same url. ugh.

I'm thinking I'm going to have to set up an elastic load balancer and use the cert from ACM in the ELB. Then I guess I won't need the lets encrypt cert on the EC2 instance anymore?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you using as the Origin Domain Name in the CloudFront config? The system-assigned `ec2-x-x-x-x.*.amazonaws.com` address, or something else?

Comment: I’m using the ec2 public origin domain name as you mentioned.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot do i need to enter a value for the Origin Path?

Comment: No, you most likely don't -- but if you did, it wouldn't cause 502 errors.  Go to the cache behavior settings and whitelist the `Host` header for forwarding to the origin.  Wait at least 5 minutes then retest.

Comment: So I switched the CNAME record back to cloudfront (i had previously changed it to the elastic IP so i could continue testing), and then I did what you suggested, and i'm no longer getting a 502 error. However, when I look at the cloudfront usage statistics, i'm not seeing any requests or anything for today, so I'm not sure it's working. That was an hour ago when i made those changes.

Comment: Those take a little time to update.  Look at your HTTP response headers to confirm the traffic is using CloudFront, or your web server access logs, which will not show your IP address -- they'll show CloudFront IP addresses.  Once confirmed, I'll post an answer to explain why this is needed and what the alternatives are.

Comment: ok, so stupid question, but that's not showing up in the response headers. How do i view the server access logs?

Comment: I was speaking of the web server access logs on your EC2 instance... wherever those might be based in the web server you are running, e.g. `/var/log/nginx`.  Response headers seen by the browser should include `Via: ... cloudfront` and `X-Cache: ... CloudFront`.

Comment: i'm getting the 502 error again now. Not sure why it took so long to reflect the DNS change.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot please see my update.

Comment: Simple steps: make up a new hostname, e.g. `origin.example.com`.  Point to EC2 in DNS.  Configure a new Lets Encrypt certificate with this new name.  Verify working with your browser.  Configure this as the Origin Domain Name in CloudFronr.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the second approach that @Kannaiyan pointed out, you don't need to move the domain name to AWS. Simply create a hosted zone and copy the NS records generated in the zone to your DNS provider. You can then easily hook up your domain name, including the apex domain, to the Cloudfront distribution.

You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57008873/2057069)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use your custom SSL with a dedicated IP, AWS is going to charge you $600 per month. CloudFront will give dedicated IP Address at the edge and takes your SSL and serve with that IP Address.

You can also import Custom SSL to your AWS Cert manager which then can be used to assign it to the CloudFront Endpoint. The only drawback with this approach is, you need to update the SSL again during cert renewal.

Other alternatives,

**Steps with a third party DNS provider.**

1. Create CNAME Record with your DNS provider.
2. Create AWS Secure Certificate with AWS certificate manager, which may require domain verification with a CNAME or email address. This is FREE.
3. Add CNAME record to your CloudFront distribution.
4. Once you receive the cert, assign the cert to CloudFront endpoint

There will be an additional round trip to query DNS to resolve to IP.

> CNAME (Resolve) --> CloudFront Host DNS Name
>   (something.cloudfront.net) --> Resolve to IP.

Alternatively, (Also the **best way to do it**)

If you move your DNS to Route 53, you can assign your CloudFront to a Distribution, that will resolve your serving domain in a single DNS request.

With the above setup, I'm not finding a need for `Lets Encrypt` cert with EC2.

More info on Custom SSL Certs with AWS on CloudFront can be found from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/).

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

**Validate SSL:**

1. Point your cloudfront origin to a S3 bucket.
2. Verify cloudfront url works without issues in connect to S3 bucket with the object.
3. Verify with Custom Domain URL to make sure custom SSL cert works.
4. Now change your origin to EC2 server.
5. Make sure you log the request and response for debugging purposes.
6. Validate your custom domain url again.
7. If you receive 5XX then, check the response from your EC2 server.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/ You don't get charged the $600 without forcing it to use SSL that does not support SNI at browser. "If you need to deliver content to browsers that don’t support SNI,"  If you can get the cert into ACM you should be fine.

Comment: @JamesKn Updated the answer, thanks for catching that. Also added a way to import SSL certs to AWS Certificate Manager and issues around it.

Comment: I think I've successfully done what you mentioned at the beginning of your answer. I imported my lets encrypt cert into ACM and used that as my custom cert for the cloudfront distribution. I'm still getting a 502 error though, which your answer doesn't address.

Comment: The $600 non-SNI SSL feature is 100% irrelevant to the question at hand, as is the mention of Route 53.

Comment: @hyphen additional information added for validation.

Comment: @Kannaiyan please see my udpate.

Comment: You can use ELB, it is going to be costly. If you are using multiple EC2 I would recommend multiple A records with health check, that will be much cheaper than ELB, unless you need all the ELB features. If you move your certs to ACM you life is going to be simplified with SSL.